# Can a table overlap another table in an email?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am designing an email with HTML and CSS, and I would like the button to overlap partly over the footer.

[image: My mockup design for reference.]

The button and footer are within a few tables, tr's, and td’s. I've tried changing the z-index on the outer tables of each, but it does not seem to help at all. The footer can overlap the button, but obviously, that isn't the goal.

I’m not the one who originally coded this section, so if it's a mess I’m sorry.I tried to clean out some of the unnecessary styles and copy on a few of the tags.

```html
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background-color: #F8F9FA; z-index: 20; margin:0 auto;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto; z-index: 20;">
              <tr>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffcc04" width="250" style="padding: 10px;">
                  <a href="https://www.pcci.edu/collegedays/" style="padding: 10px;width:250px;display: block;
text-decoration: none;border:0; text-align: center;font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px;
font-family: sans-serif; color: #00568d; background: #ffcc04; line-height:17px; 
text-transform: uppercase;" class="button_link">See College Days Details </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table width="100%" class="Wrapper" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color:#f2f2f2; z-index: 10;">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="background-color:transparent;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; border-top-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; border-right-style: none;
border-left-style: none; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px; border-color: #00568d; margin-bottom: 40px;">
      <!--[if(gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
style="width: 600px;"><tr><td align="center"><![endif]-->

      <table width="100%" class="Container" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="max-width:600px; z-index:10;">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" style="background-color: #00568d">
            <table width="100%" class="Column-1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
              <tr>
                <td align="center">
                  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tr class="text">
                      <td>
                        <p>...</p>
                        <p>...</p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <!--[if(gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Am I seeking out something which cannot be done with code? Is it even possible to make the button’s table overlap the other? My coworker said if I can’t figure this out, I can just do it like our normal buttons, but I didn't want to give up just yet.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried - without that we don't know how to help you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Email client support will be very spotty but have you tried negative margin on the table, or on the button itself?

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo, when I add a negative margin-bottom to the button it just makes the footer overlap.

Comment: @disinfor, added the code. Kind of difficult to minimize, but I tried somewhat.

Comment: @agrm, just tried that and it didn't do anything for me.

Comment: In my experience, emails generally don't behave too well with excessive css. Keep it simple.

Comment: @Trin you posted what we needed to see. Thanks! As a note, you going to have a hard time with this - most email clients do not support the `position` property which you'll need for `z-index`. Also, negative margins are spotty. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ check that out for supported properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to span the "button" over two rows using `rowspan`:

```html
<table width="100% border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto; z-index: 20;">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td rowspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#ffcc04" width="250" style="padding: 10px;">
            <a href="https://www.pcci.edu/collegedays/" style="padding: 10px;width:250px;display: block;
text-decoration: none;border:0; text-align: center;font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px;
font-family: sans-serif; color: #00568d; background: #ffcc04; line-height:17px; 
text-transform: uppercase;" class="button_link">See College Days Details </a>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor="#00568d">&nbsp;</td><td bgcolor="#00568d">&nbsp;</td></tr>

    <tr bgcolor="#00568d">
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr bgcolor="#00568d">
        <td colspan="3" align="center">
            (c) Copyright Pensacola Christian College...
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Was about to suggest a solution using three columns, where those surrounding the button consisted of another nested table split in two. Beat be to it, and with a more elegant solution! (Oh, and it's been a while since I upvoted a table-based answer. Email clients... :-)

Comment: @agrm Yes, seems very old fashioned. However, for some reason email clients seem to cope better with old style html and limited css.

Comment: @LeeTaylor, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: @syfer You're referring to CSS columns https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-span , not table column spanning. colspan != column-span

Comment: @LeeTaylor my bad I was wrong but still `colspan` has issues in Outlook if placed in the wrong place. Its in one of the answers for a `colspan` question.

Comment: Great solution! I was going to suggest a my usual technique to use a background image but this trumps that completely. @Trin, I suggest avoiding any use of position, z-index and margin:0 auto (for centring). z-index and position aren't supported in most email clients and you're safer using align="center" to centre elements as opposed to margin:auto.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been answered but here is method without colspan which does not have very good support in few cases and some email clients.

Advantage with this is you have a bullet proof button which will work across all email clients the same way (and the whole button will be clickable). Also its maintainable, meaning if you delete a column by mistake colspan will not make a mess in email clients.

```html
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" align="left" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#F8F9FA" style="height: 25px;">&zwnj;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#00568d" style="height: 25px;">&zwnj;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table></td>
              <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#00568d">
                  
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: auto;">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #ffcc04; border-radius: 0px; text-align: center;" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffcc04" align="center"><a href="" target="_blank" style="display: inline-block; color: #00568d; background-color: #ffcc04; border: solid 1px #ffcc04; border-radius: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; padding: 12px 45px; text-transform: capitalize; border-color: #ffcc04;">Take action now</a></td>
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
              <td width="33%" align="left" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#F8F9FA" style="height: 25px;">&zwnj;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#00568d" style="height: 25px;">&zwnj;</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#00568d" style="color:#ffffff;padding:0px 20px 20px 20px;">Footer</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show evidence that `colspan` has limited support.

Comment: Sorry if it seems I am saying you answer is wrong. I am simply saying what the discussion was about on Litmus Community and Stack Overflow as well. https://litmus.com/community/discussions/408-trouble-with-colspan-in-outlook-07-10-13.

Comment: I avoid colspan because I always prefer using nested tables but have never had any issues with colspan when I do use it. Typically it's people's misuse/carelessness that causes issues with this property.